# Redux state is undefined in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am currently following [this](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html) tutorial. I've hit a bit of a snag involving `mapStateToProps` in the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Voting from './voting';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    pair: state.getIn(['vote','pair']),
    winner: state.get('winner')
  };
}

const VotingContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Voting);
export default VotingContainer;
```

Here is the Voting component that's imported:

```
import React from 'react';
import Vote from './Vote';
import Winner from './winner';

const Voting = ({pair,vote,hasVoted,winner}) =>
  <div>
    {winner ? <Winner winner={winner}/>  :
      <Vote pair={pair} vote={vote} hasVoted={hasVoted}/>
    }
  </div>

export default Voting;
```

It is supposed to render two buttons from the `pair` prop. The `vote` prop is a function that will be executed on click, `hasVoted` disables buttons when true and winner only renders the winner component as shown.

The state is expected to be an immutableJS map that looks like this:

```
Map({
  vote:{
    pair:List.of('Movie A','Movie B')
  }
});
```

Instead I am getting an error saying that state is undefined in the state.getIn line.

The code setting the state is in index:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

const socket = io(document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + ':8090');
socket.on('state', state => store.dispatch({
  type: 'SET_STATE',
  state
}));
```

I have logged `store.getState()`after setting and it is as expected but `undefined` in `mapStateToProps`. I also logged the state variable in above context and it's also as expected.

I also set the state normally and it surprisingly works!:

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'SET_STATE',
  state: {
    vote: {
      pair: ['Movie A', 'Movie B']
    }
  }
});
```

The value of state above is exactly what is received from the server

Lastly here's what my reducer looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Map, fromJS} from 'immutable';

const reducer = (state = Map(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATE':
      return state.merge(action.state);
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I realised that `mapStateToProps` is not being called after the `store.dispatch()`. I went through the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) for the possible reasons `mapStateToProps` is not being called and it's not one of them.

Comment: i suggest you add `redux-logger` to existing middlewares to verify if the actions are properly dispatched or not; it could give us a better idea

Comment: @Deadfish Thanks for the suggestion. I used redux-logger and the action is being dispatched correctly although I don't know why the previous state is undefined since my initial state is an empty Map. I also realised that for the one involving the server, mapStateToProps is not called after the dispatch.

Comment: i think the `mapStateToProps` is not called when the state is mutated; but your reducer code looks fine; could you share your whole code through github or gist; something must have been wrong with the way it was setup

Comment: @Deadfish Sure, [server](https://github.com/esaminu/redux-voting-server) and the [client](https://github.com/esaminu/redux-voting-client)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You reducer doesn't have a default action in switch statement. Which is why even though you mentioned the initial state in reducer params, undefined is returned as store initial state

```
import React from 'react';
import {Map,fromJS} from 'immutable';

const reducer = (state = Map() ,action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SET_STATE': return state.merge(action.state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

Adding the default statement will fix the issue :)

Comment: thanks so much @Deadfish! I literally redid [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9boMnm5X9ak&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwheJHvseC3I0HuYI2f46oAK&index=2) entire playlist just because of this error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here too because I had failed to pass my rootreducer function to my `createStore` method. I had:

```
const store = createStore(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

I needed:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer(), applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```