# Higher Order Functions Unable to Access Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a higher order function and inside that I am trying to access the state property "isAuthenticated" which is stored in Redux. For some reason is it saying state is undefined.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export default function(ComposedComponent) {

    class Authenticate extends Component {

        render() {

            return (
                <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
        }
    }


    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I use the higher order component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store = {store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <BaseLayout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={App} />
      <Route path='/profile' component={requireAuth(Profile)} />
    </Switch>
    </BaseLayout>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have checked and redux state is initialized correctly since I am using it in order pages. What am I missing in my higher order function which is preventing it from accessing the redux global state.

[image]

UPDATE: reducer code

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'AUTHENTICATED':
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: action.value != null ? true : false 
      }
  }
}

export default reducer
```

Comment: Do you use combineReducers and how do you use your HOC

Comment: No! I only have one reducer.

Comment: What is the error that you receive and where does it point, because your code seems to be correct

Comment: I updated the question with screenshot.

Comment: What is in your reducer? Maybe it is the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976134/redux-state-is-undefined-in-mapstatetoprops where you need to `return state` as a default

Comment: Just added code for reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing default return in reducer => in initial, when you doesn't dispatch action 'AUTHENTICATED', your store is `undefined`.

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTHENTICATED":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: action.value != null ? true : false
      };
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};
```

Comment: you should `return state` instead of `initialState` otherwise, it will reset redux state to its initial state every time it goes through this reducer without an `action.type == 'AUTHENTICATED'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can manage to connect `mapStateToProps` as in your example. Instead, I would import `ComposedComponent` and use redux to connect `Authenticate`:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ComposedComponent from './PATH_TO/ComposedComponent'

class Authenticate extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
     )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate)
```

Now you shouldn't have any issues accessing `isAuthenticated` from your store.

Comment: I cannot use this approach as I need a higher order component.